# Add central dock widget to visbility context menu in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, widget, contextmenu, visibility

I add various dock widgets to my window through `addDockWidget`, and one main widget through `setCentralWidget`. The widgets added with `addDockWidget` are automatically added *(the context menu is generated by Qt)* to a context menu list that appear when right-clicking, allowing the user to toggle the visibility of the various dock widgets:

[image: context menu]

However, the widget added through `setCentralWidget` is absent from this menu, and if it's "closed" it can't be made visible again through the context menu. How can I add the central widget to this menu?

Comment: Please show the code you have that creates/shows the menu.  I'm finding it difficult to understand how you can add some widgets (the docks) but not others.

Comment: @G.M. The menu seems to be automatically generated by Qt when using `addDockWidget`. It's not something that I coded.